# Can somebody explain this change of behavior for flatMap between Swift 3 & 4?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

I'd like to understand why Swift 4 and Swift 3.2 have different `flatMap` behaviors.

Consider the following code:

```
let myURLArray: ([URL]) = [ URL(string: "https://www.google.fr")! ]
let result = myURLArray.flatMap { $0.absoluteString }
print(result)
```

#### With Swift 3.2:

`result` is interpreted as a `[String]` and the output is:

```
["https://www.google.fr"]
```

#### With Swift 4:

`result` is interpreted as a `[String.Element]` and the output is:

```
["h", "t", "t", "p", "s", ":", "/", "/", "w", "w", "w", ".", "g", "o", "o", "g", "l", "e", ".", "f", "r"]
```

---

I cannot find the item describing this change of behavior in [Swift 4's release notes](https://swift.org/blog/swift-4-0-released/). Can anybody explain?

Comment: And the solution is to replace `flatMap` by `map` (since `absoluteString` does not return an optional). That should behave identically in both Swift versions.

Comment: In `Swift` **2-3** `String` **is not** `Collection`, in `Swift` **1, 4** it [**is** `Collection`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0163-string-revision-1.md). And `flatMap` "lifts" collection's content one level up.

Comment: With respect to the Swift 4 release notes: This is a consequence of SE-0163.